# Public and Internal members in an Internal class?

Tags: c#, class, public, access-modifiers, internal

Ok, so this may be a bit of a silly question, and there's certainly the obvious answer, but I was curious if I've missed any subtleties here.

Is there any difference in terms of visibility/usability between a `public` member declared in an `internal` class and an `internal` member declared in an `internal` class?

i.e. between

```
internal class Foo
{
    public void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
internal class Foo
{
    internal void Bar()
    {
    }
}
```

If you declared the method as `public` and also `virtual`, and then overrode it in a derived class that is `public`, the reason for using this modifier is clear. However, is this the only situation... am I missing something else?

Comment: _If you declared the method as public and also virtual, and then overrode it in a derived class that is public_ **meeeep!**: You are not allowed to increase visibility, only the other way round: You can create a derived class of a public class which is internal (or even nested and private)

Comment: Googlers take note: This near-duplicate [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302236/why-use-a-public-method-in-an-internal-class/9302642#9302642) contains another particularly excellent answer.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Consider this case:

```
public interface IBar { void Bar(); }
internal class C : IBar
{
    public void Bar() { }
}
```

Here C.Bar cannot be marked as internal; doing so is an error because C.Bar can be accessed by a caller of D.GetBar():

```
public class D
{
    public static IBar GetBar() { return new C(); } 
}
```

---

A commenter asked a follow-up question: is an *explicit* implementation of an interface method considered to be *public*, or *private*?  (C# does not allow you to put an access modifier on an explicit implementation.)

Take a step back and think about what exactly is "public" or "private" about a member: people think wrong things like *"private means that a method cannot be called from outside the class"*, but that's not true; the class could make a delegate to a private method, pass it to anyone, and they can then call a private method.

Rather, accessibility determines where the **name** of a thing can be used! Explicit interface implementations do not add a name to the class declaration space in the first place; they can only be referred to by name via the interface, not the class.  It really doesn't make sense to think of explicit interface implementations as public *or* private because they don't have a name you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks Eric, this is another good case. So effectively interface implementation and class inheritance are the reasons for allowing either the `public` or `internal` modifier in an `internal` class. In other cases, they are equivalent it would seem.

Comment: Eric also answers an almost identical question at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9302642/398015 There are additional details in his post that add considerable substance to the answer above.

Answer (score 53):

A `public` member is still just `internal` when in an `internal` class.

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> The accessibility of a member can never be greater than the accessibility of its containing type. For example, a public method declared in an internal type has only internal accessibility

Think of it this way, I would access a `public` property on....? A class I can't see? :)

Eric's answer is very important in this case, if it's exposed via an interface and not directly it *does* make a difference, just depends if you're in that situation with the member you're dealing with.

Comment: Yes, this was indeed exactly my thought except for in the case Eric pointed out (as well as the one in my original question).

Comment: It also makes a difference when you use reflection. Default parameter-less methods like Type.GetMethods() only return public members. And the public method inside the internal class still knows that it is public.

Comment: "The accessibility of a member can never be greater than the accessibility of its containing type." While that holds true for some cases, a `public` member of a `private` class is clearly a wider scope than a `private` member of a `private` class (The former being project wide, the latter being class only).

Comment: @Deanna yes...but that doesn't make the former statement false, you're comparing peers not containers with that - where things are accessible doesn't change, since you can't access a public member from outside it's private class container.

Comment: So, if I define my class as "internal," do I change my members to "internal" as well? Or should I just let them be public?

Answer (score 3):

Just faced with another example where there *is* difference between those two, when used from XAML in WPF.

XAML:

```
<Button Tag="{x:Static vm:Foo+Bar.e1}" />
```

Code with `internal` enum compiles successfully:

```
internal class Foo
{
    internal enum Bar
    {
        e1,
        e2,
    }
}
```

But surprisingly changing it to `public` results in error:

```
internal class Foo
{
    public enum Bar
    {
        e1,
        e2,
    }
}
```

The last example produces compilation error:

> error MC3064: Only public or internal classes can be used within markup. 'Bar' type is not public or internal.

Unfortunately, I can't explain what's wrong with `public` in this case. My guess is "just because WPF works that way". Just change modifier of the nested class to `internal` to get rid of error.

Comment: Thank you for this! I would never guess what was wrong with my XAML

Answer (score 2):

`public` members of an `internal` class can override `public` members of `public` base classes and, therefore, be a little more exposed... if indirectly.

Answer (score 1):

If it comes to reflection it matters if the member is public or not:

For example you even could pass a nested private class to a WPF binding and the binding would work against the public properties just as usual.